# How to use the data stored in cache for another function in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I have created a sample spring boot application which have a class "**CacheManagement** "where I have a function "**getAllValue**" which return the a customer object whose values I need to cache.
This class also have a function **checkCache**  which uses the data from cache. How Can I implement this. Somebody please help me on this. I am providing the class I have written.PFB the class

```
@Service
public class CacheManagement {
    
    @Cacheable(value = "service",key = "list")
    public Customer getAllValue(){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        System.out.println("Inside cache");
        customer.setId("1");
        customer.setName("Shilpa");
        return customer;
    }
    
    public String checkCache() {
    Customer cus = getAllValue();
    System.out.println(cus.toString());
    return "1";
    
    }

}
```

PFB the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) {
        CacheManagement cacheService = new CacheManagement();
        cacheService.getAllValue();
        cacheService.checkCache();
                
        
        
    }
}
```

According  to my need the **sysout** statement should only print once right? But my issue is it is printing twice .Means the **getAllValue()** call from **checkCache()** method is calling the function itself not fetching data from cache.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Instead of `cacheService.checkCache()`,  call  `cacheService.getAllValue()`  . Is it printing twice ?

Comment: Your verification prints the `"Inside cache"` twice , as the call from `checkCache()` is an internal method call. `Cacheable` works on proxy

Comment: The scenario is i need the cached value in checkCache() function.

Comment: I will answer with an example and brief explanation on the concept.

Comment: yes it is working fine now.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. `CacheManagement cacheService = new CacheManagement();` creates an instance which is not a Spring container managed bean. The Spring magic will not work here . You should get a Spring container managed bean of `cacheManagement` for all your Spring framework support to kickin.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    CacheManagement cacheService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) {
        cacheService.getAllValue();
        cacheService.checkCache();
    }
}
```

2.Assuming you have enabled caching using [@EnableCaching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html) ( Refer [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) )

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
...
}
```

The Spring Caching works with the help of Spring AOP and Spring AOP works on proxies. Calling `getAllValue()` from within a method of the same class ( here `checkCache()`) is called a self-invocation. Spring AOP will not be able to advice the method call in this case , as it will not go through the proxy and hence the caching logic fails to work.

To understand this concept in detail , do refer the official spring reference documentation : [Understanding AOP Proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) . Read through the section starting with *The key thing to understand here is that the client code inside the main(..)*

The resolution to your issue is to make sure the `checkValue()` call goes through the proxy so that the cached result is returned. Since you need the method (`checkValue()`) as part of the same bean , a self reference , will do it.

You must read through the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) on the same topic though to understand the implications. Section starting with *As of 4.3, @Autowired also considers self references for injection ..*

Following code should fix the issue for you

```
@Service
public class CacheManagement {

    @Autowired
    CacheManagement self;
    
    @Cacheable(value = "service",key = "list")
    public Customer getAllValue(){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        System.out.println("Inside cache");
        customer.setId("1");
        customer.setName("Shilpa");
        return customer;
    }
    
    public String checkCache() {
    Customer cus = self.getAllValue();
    System.out.println(cus.toString());
    return "1";
    
    }

}
```

Read more on caching [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.8/reference/html/integration.html#cache)